# Symfony2/Doctrine2 OneToMany related entities do not have ID of the inverse side

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 related entities, Invoice & InvoiceRow, and I have a form to let people create new invoices.

I also have some fixtures of test data that I load to seed the database with test data and no matter how I persist the entities to the database the `invoice_id` in InvoiceRow is always `null`

In the fixtures I've tried persisting the Invoice

InvoiceRow.php:

```
namespace Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
Class InvoiceRow {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * The invoice row amount, stored in "bottle tops", ie £1.00 is 10000 bottle tops
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $amount;

    /**
     * The invoice this row belongs to.
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Invoice", inversedBy="rows")
     * @var integer
     **/
    protected $invoice;

    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setAmount($amount) {
        $this->amount = $amount * 10000;
    }

    public function getAmount() {
        return $this->amount / 10000;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the invoice this row is attached to.
     *
     * @return Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Invoice The invoice.
     */
    public function getInvoice() {
        return $this->invoice;
    }

    /**
     * Set the invoice this row belongs to.
     *
     * @param Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Invoice $newinvoice The invoice.
     */
    public function setInvoice($invoice) {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Invoice.php

```
<?php

namespace Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Sylius\Bundle\AddressingBundle\Model\AddressInterface;

use Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Exception\MerchantUpdateException;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
Class Invoice {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $reference;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $issueDate;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\InvoiceRow", mappedBy="invoice", cascade="persist")
     */
    protected $rows;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Settleup\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    protected $merchant;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\InvoiceAddress", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $invoiceAddress;

    /**
     * undocumented function
     *
     * @return void
     * @author 
     **/
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rows = new ArrayCollection();

        $this->issueDate = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * undocumented function
     *
     * @return void
     * @author 
     **/
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the rows on this invoice.
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     * @author 
     **/
    public function getRows()
    {
        return $this->rows;
    }

    /**
     * Set the reference for this invoice.
     *
     * @return void
     * @author 
     **/
    public function setReference($reference)
    {
        $this->reference = $reference;
    }

    /**
     * Returnt he invoice reference.
     *
     * @return string
     * @author 
     **/
    public function getReference()
    {
        return $this->reference;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the date this invoice was issued.
     *
     * @param  \DateTime $issueDate The date the invoice was issued.
     * @return void
     * @author 
     **/
    public function setIssueDate(\DateTime $issueDate)
    {
        $this->issueDate = $issueDate;
    }

    /**
     * Return the date the invoice was raised.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     * @author 
     **/
    public function getIssueDate()
    {
        return $this->issueDate;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the collections of rows that make up this invoice.
     *
     * @return void
     * @author 
     **/
    public function setRows(ArrayCollection $rows)
    {
        $this->rows = $rows;
    }

    /**
     * Return the merchant for this invoice.
     *
     * @return Settleup\UserBundle\Entity\User
     * @author 
     **/
    public function getMerchant()
    {
        return $this->merchant;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of SyliusAddress, the address this invoice is for.
     *
     * @return Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\InvoiceAddress
     * @author 
     **/
    public function getInvoiceAddress()
    {
        return $this->invoiceAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the address for this invoice
     *
     * @param Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\InvoiceAddress invoiceAddress The address this invoice is for.
     *
     * @return void
     * @author 
     **/
    public function setInvoiceAddress(AddressInterface $invoiceAddress)
    {
        $this->invoiceAddress = $invoiceAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Add rows
     *
     * @param \Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\InvoiceRow $rows
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function addRow(\Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\InvoiceRow $rows)
    {
        $this->rows[] = $rows;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove rows
     *
     * @param \Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\InvoiceRow $rows
     */
    public function removeRow(\Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\InvoiceRow $rows)
    {
        $this->rows->removeElement($rows);
    }

    /**
     * Set merchant
     *
     * @param \Settleup\UserBundle\Entity\User $merchant
     * @return Invoice
     */
    public function setMerchant(\Settleup\UserBundle\Entity\User $merchant = null)
    {
        if ($this->id == null) {
            $this->merchant = $merchant;
        } else {
            throw new MerchantUpdateException("Unable to update the merchant for this invoice, you can only assign a merchant when creating the invoice.");
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @TODO Find out why this method is needed.
     *
     * @return void
     * @author 
     **/
    public function getAddresses()
    {
    }

    public function setAddresses() {}
}
```

I've got a form that I use to populate rows in both tables:

```
class InvoiceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('reference')
            ->add('rows', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => 'invoice_row',
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false
                ))
            ->add('invoiceAddress', 'sylius_address');

            $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                function(FormEvent $event) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();

                    $form->add('merchant', 'hidden');
                }
            );
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Settleup\InvoiceBundle\Entity\Invoice',
            'cascade_validation' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'settleup_invoicebundle_invoicetype';
    }
}
```

When that form is saved using an action on the controller:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entity  = new Invoice();

    $form = $this->createForm(new InvoiceType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity->setMerchant($this->getUser());

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('invoice_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    } else {

    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

both rows have all the correct data except InvoiceRow is missing the invoice_id.

Comment: try change ```cascade="persist"``` to ```cascade={"persist"}``` at rows definition in Invoice.

Comment: Thanks Kibao but that's not fixed the issue.

Comment: So you should try add ```$row->setInvoice($this)``` to method ```Invoice::addRow($row)```

Comment: At that point though the invoice won't have an ID will it? It won't have been persisted to the DB yet?

Comment: It wont have an id but doctrine is clever enough to insert the invoice and use it's id in the invoice row insert.  kibao's method is the same method we usually implement

Comment: I have tried @kibao's solution and it does work for both my cases (via a form & fixtures).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but may be useful for others

1) Try persisting the owning side (the one with FK) i.e. invoiceRow

2) I had issues persisting a related entity because the id field didn't follow the defaults. Adding this made it work:

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Personas", fetch="EAGER", inversedBy="cuentasCorriente", 
 * cascade={"persist", "refresh"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="persona_id", referencedColumnName="ID", nullable=false)
```

referencedColumnName="ID" see "ID" != "id"
as I added Doctrine to a legacy system, had no choice.